# I need to remove Woocommerce variations from database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce shop with about 3000 products. They were imported via XML file. Many of the products have variations but some of the variations had no price.

I would like to delete all variations that have no price but leave the rest. I'm thinking that I can do this somehow via phpMyAdmin. I would like to know how variations are stored in the database and what function I could use to remove variations of a specific value.

Comment: Variations are simply posts with the post_type of `product_variation`. Price, however, is stored as post_meta.

Comment: Thanks @helgatheviking ... So would I use something like the following:

'UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, '0','');'

How do I specify to only replace values in the price post_meta?

Comment: My SQL isn't very good, so I can only tell you how the data is stored. Try [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38511/delete-posts-based-on-post-meta-data)